# Expectation of ratio between product of gaussian r.v.'s and generalized gamma r.v

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, gaussian

Given
\begin{equation}\label{eq:definition_of_z}
\begin{split}
\textbf{Z} = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
{z}_{11} & {z}_{12} & \cdots & {z}_{1P} \\
{z}_{21} & {z}_{22} & \cdots & {z}_{2P} \\
{z}_{31} & {z}_{32} & \cdots & {z}_{3P} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
{z}_{M1} & {z}_{M2} & \cdots & {z}_{MP} \\ \end{array} \right] =  \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
\textbf{z}_{1} & \textbf{z}_{2} & \cdots & \textbf{z}_{P} \\ \end{array} \right]
\end{split}
\end{equation}

where the $z_{mp}$ are i.i.d. $\forall \ m,p$ with distribution $z_{mp} \sim \mathcal{CN}(0,c)$ and $\textbf{z}_{i}$ represents each of the columns of  $\textbf{Z} \sim \mathcal{CN}(\textbf{0}_{M \times P},\text{cM}\textbf{I}_{P})$.

Other necessary definition is given by

\begin{equation}\label{eq:definition_of_z_z}
\textbf{Z}^{H} \textbf{Z} =  \left[\begin{array}{c}
\textbf{z}_{1}^{H} \\
\textbf{z}_{2}^{H} \\
\vdots \\
\textbf{z}_{P}^{H} \\ \end{array} \right]  \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
\textbf{z}_{1} & \textbf{z}_{2} & \cdots & \textbf{z}_{P} \\ \end{array} \right] = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
\textbf{z}_{1}^{H}\textbf{z}_{1} & \textbf{z}_{1}^{H} \textbf{z}_{2} & \cdots & \textbf{z}_{1}^{H} \textbf{z}_{P} \\
\textbf{z}_{2}^{H} \textbf{z}_{1} & \textbf{z}_{2}^{H} \textbf{z}_{2} & \cdots & \textbf{z}_{2}^{H} \textbf{z}_{P} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\textbf{z}_{P}^{H} \textbf{z}_{1} & \textbf{z}_{P}^{H} \textbf{z}_{2} & \cdots & \textbf{z}_{P}^{H} \textbf{z}_{P} \\ \end{array} \right] 
\end{equation}

Next we define the following ratio:

\begin{equation}\label{eq:channel_matrix}
  \frac{ \textbf{Z}^{H} \textbf{Z} }{ \text{Tr} \left(    \textbf{Z}^{H} \textbf{Z}     \right)^{2} } = \frac{ \textbf{Z}^{H} \textbf{Z} }{ \left(   \textbf{z}_{1}^{H}\textbf{z}_{1} + \textbf{z}_{2}^{H}\textbf{z}_{2} + \cdots + \textbf{z}_{P}^{H}\textbf{z}_{P}     \right)^{2} }   
\end{equation}

where $\text{Tr}$ is the Trace operator.

It is important to note that the elements of the main diagonal of $\textbf{Z}^{H} \textbf{Z}$, namely  $\textbf{z}_{1}^{H}\textbf{z}_{1}, \ \textbf{z}_{2}^{H}\textbf{z}_{2}, \ \cdots, \  \textbf{z}_{P}^{H}\textbf{z}_{P} \sim \Gamma(M,2c)$.

I'd like to prove that the following expectation is equal to 0.

\begin{equation}\label{eq:4}
\mathbb{E} \left\lbrace \frac{\textbf{z}_{i}^{H}\textbf{z}_{j}}{\left(   \textbf{z}_{1}^{H}\textbf{z}_{1} + \textbf{z}_{2}^{H}\textbf{z}_{2} + \cdots + \textbf{z}_{P}^{H}\textbf{z}_{P}     \right)^{2} } \right\rbrace = 0, \ \text{when} \  i \neq j.
\end{equation}

I know for a fact that the above statement is true due to some Matlab simulations I ran but I'd like to prove that mathematically.

It's also worth mentioning that $\textbf{z}_{1}^{H}\textbf{z}_{1} + \textbf{z}_{2}^{H}\textbf{z}_{2} + \cdots + \textbf{z}_{P}^{H}\textbf{z}_{P}$ results in a scalar random variable.

Comment: What's $z^{H}$?  And what's $\mathcal{CN}(0,c)$?

Comment: $H$ is the conjugate transpose of a matrix also called Hermitian conjugate. The second is the circularly-symmetric complex distribution.

Comment: Isn’t it enough to use a symmetry argument? The distribution of $z_i$ and $-z_i$ is the same. Replacing $z_i$ by $-z_i$ in the expectation reveals that it is equal to its negative, hence zero, unless $i = j$.

Comment: @student, yes, it would suffice. Would you like to answer that question with the symmetry argument? Let me know, otherwise I will try to post an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @FelipeAugustodeFigueiredo If you feel this is enough to make an answer, go ahead.

Comment: Among the advantages of \operatorname{Tr} rather than \text{Tr} are that (1) you get proper spacing in expressions like $3\operatorname{Tr}(A),$ so you don't see $3\text{Tr}(A)$ instead, and (2) the spacing is context-dependent, so that the space to the right of $\operatorname{Tr}$ in $\operatorname{Tr}(A)$ is different from that in $\operatorname{Tr} A.$ That is why it is standard to use \operatorname{Tr} rather than \text{Tr}. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have 
$$\mathbb{E} [ | \textbf{z}_1^{H} \textbf{z}_2 | ] \le\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[|\textbf{z}_1|^2] \mathbb{E}[|\textbf{z}_2|^2]} = \mathbb{E}[|\textbf{z}_1|^2]<\infty,$$

hence, $\mathbb{E} [ \textbf{z}_1^{H} \textbf{z}_2 ]$ exists and is finite. 
Therefore and because the joint distribution of the pair $(-\textbf{z}_1^H,\textbf{z}_2)$ is the same as that of $(\textbf{z}_1^H, \textbf{z}_2)$, we conclude that 
$$\mathbb{E}[\textbf{z}_1^{H} \textbf{z}_2] = \mathbb{E} [ (-\textbf{z}_1)^H \textbf{z}_2 ] = 0.$$

If $\textbf{z}_{i} \forall i$ is a vector composed of i.i.d. random variables following a symmetric distribution around 0, then
$$\mathbb{E}[\textbf{g}(\textbf{z}_{1}, \textbf{z}_{2}, \ldots, \textbf{z}_{M})^{H} \textbf{h}(\textbf{z}_{1}, \textbf{z}_{2}, \ldots, \textbf{z}_{M})] = 0,$$
where $\textbf{g}(\textbf{z}_{1}, \textbf{z}_{2}, \ldots, \textbf{z}_{M})$ and $ \textbf{h}(\textbf{z}_{1}, \textbf{z}_{2}, \ldots, \textbf{z}_{M})$ are functions of the random variables $\textbf{z}_{i} \forall i$, which present the same symmetric distribution around 0.

**Proof**

First, by using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we find that
$$\mathbb{E} [ | \textbf{g}(\textbf{z}_{1}, \textbf{z}_{2}, \ldots, \textbf{z}_{M})^{H} \textbf{h}(\textbf{z}_{1}, \textbf{z}_{2}, \ldots, \textbf{z}_{M}) | ] \le\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[|\textbf{g}(\textbf{z}_{1}, \textbf{z}_{2}, \ldots, \textbf{z}_{M})|^2] \mathbb{E}[|\textbf{h}(\textbf{z}_{1}, \textbf{z}_{2}, \ldots, \textbf{z}_{M})|^2]} = \mathbb{E}[|\textbf{g}(\textbf{z}_{1}, \textbf{z}_{2}, \ldots, \textbf{z}_{M})|^2]<\infty,$$
and thus, $\mathbb{E}[\textbf{g}(\textbf{z}_{1}, \textbf{z}_{2}, \ldots, \textbf{z}_{M})^{H} \textbf{h}(\textbf{z}_{1}, \textbf{z}_{2}, \ldots, \textbf{z}_{M})]$ exists and if finite. Next, as $\textbf{z}_{i} \forall i$ is a vector composed of i.i.d. random variables following a symmetric distribution around 0, then, the distribution $f_{\textbf{z}_{i}}(\textbf{z}_{i})$ is the same as $f_{\textbf{z}_{i}}(-\textbf{z}_{i})$. Therefore, the joint distribution $f_{\textbf{z}_{1},\textbf{z}_{2},\ldots,\textbf{z}_{M}}(\textbf{z}_{1}, \textbf{z}_{2}, \ldots, \textbf{z}_{M})$ is the same as that of $f_{\textbf{z}_{1},\textbf{z}_{2},\ldots,\textbf{z}_{M}}(-\textbf{z}_{1}, \textbf{z}_{2}, \ldots, \textbf{z}_{M})$. We also know that the distribution of $\textbf{g}(\textbf{z}_{1}, \textbf{z}_{2}, \ldots, \textbf{z}_{M})$ is equal to the distribution of $\textbf{g}(-\textbf{z}_{1}, \textbf{z}_{2}, \ldots, \textbf{z}_{M})$ and that the distribution of $\textbf{h}(\textbf{z}_{1}, \textbf{z}_{2}, \ldots, \textbf{z}_{M})$ is equal to the distribution of $\textbf{h}(-\textbf{z}_{1}, \textbf{z}_{2}, \ldots, \textbf{z}_{M})$. Therefore, we conclude that $\mathbb{E}[\textbf{g}(\textbf{z}_{1}, \textbf{z}_{2}, \ldots, \textbf{z}_{M})^{H} \textbf{h}(\textbf{z}_{1}, \textbf{z}_{2}, \ldots, \textbf{z}_{M})] = \mathbb{E} [(-\textbf{g}(\textbf{z}_{1}, \textbf{z}_{2}, \ldots, \textbf{z}_{M}))^{H} \textbf{h}(\textbf{z}_{1}, \textbf{z}_{2}, \ldots, \textbf{z}_{M})] ] = 0$.